# Auto refresh google sheet in Android phone

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm having a google sheet query working well for me in my Android mobile....

=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UNIQUE({IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/indices","Table",1);IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/indices","Table",2);IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/indices","Table",3);IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/indices","Table",4)}),"arrow_drop_up"," "),"arrow_drop_down",""),"*",""))),"Select Col1, Col4, Col7, Col3, Col6, Col9, Col10")

Now I want it to get auto refreshed every 20min. Can anyone help me plz ??
Plz remember I'm using Android mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UNIQUE({
 IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/indices","Table",1);
 IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/indices","Table",2);
 IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/indices","Table",3);
 IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/indices","Table",4)}),
 "arrow_drop_up"," "),"arrow_drop_down",""),"*",""))),
 "Select Col1, Col4, Col7, Col3, Col6, Col9, Col10", ROUND(NOW()-NOW()))
```

with:

[image]

Comment: I'm using Google sheet Android app and there is no such settings for spreadsheet. Plz is there any formula for auto refresh???